# stm32f407 ADC cannot read data

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, adc, stm32f4

i need some help.

i built custom board and had problem with my adc reading, it's not software problem...yet.
my question is really hardware. it might be my lack of understanding from reading STM32f407 manual book. so i have my **microcontroller STM32f407zgt6 with LQFP144 package**. and i fail to read the ADC. i use stm32cubeide for programming but my programming is very simple since i follow this link https://deepbluembedded.com/stm32-light-sensor-ldr-interfacing-ambient-light-sensor-project/. my question is:

do i have to connect pin VREF+ to VDDA externally to activate the ADC?
cause in STM32f103 with LQFP48. the VREF+ pin doesn't exist and the manual says that it's internally connected to VDDA pin. can i assume that the same rules can be applied to STM32f407ZGT6? or the external connection of VREF+ -> VDDA is mandatory since it is using LQFP144 package? cause i didn't connect it in my custom board and left the VREF+ pin hanging.

i just wanna use the ADC VREF+ = VDDA in LQFP144, so i assume that it is internally connected, is my assumption wrong?

here is my confusion on STM32F4 manual:
[image]
and
[image]

please help. i might have a false design on my custom board then...

Comment: This would be more on-topic on [Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), but FWIW (as a mere software engineer) I suspect you do need to wire up the VREF pin.

Comment: If the package has dedicated Vref+ it's not connected to Vdda internally. It's clearly stated at the bottom of each image here.

Answer (score 1):

In the smaller packages Vref is connected internaly just to save external pins.

In the larger packages Vref can be connected to a different power rail - more stable or slightly different, like 3.0V. And there is no configuration options to connect Vref to Vdda. The datasheed states explicitly in the "General operation conditions" chapter:

[image: From the datasheet]

And in most cases, Vref is just wired to Vdda.